# jQuery animation don't work after two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I was trying working on animation through jQuery and I faced a problem that the div box work for only 2 clicks. Any kind of help is appreciated.
Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#one").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      top: '250px'
    });
  });

  $("#sec").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      bottom: '250px'
    });
  });

  $("#thi").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      right: '250px'
    });
  });

  $("#for").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      left: '250px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: grey;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="one">DOWN</button>
<button id="sec">TOP</button>
<button id="thi">LEFT</button>
<button id="for">RIGHT</button>

<br><br>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Here is my code link: https://jsfiddle.net/djmayank/mcutmbcy/1/

Comment: Just one ready function is enough :)

Comment: I have done that but still, the problem is there.

Comment: Here is the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mcutmbcy/10/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mcutmbcy/16/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcutmbcy/9/)**.

You could "increase/decrease" just the `top/right` offsets using `+=` and `-=` :

```
$(function(){
    $("#one").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({top: '+=25px'});
    });
    $("#sec").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({top: '-=25px'});
    });
    $("#thi").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({right: '+=25px'});
    });
    $("#for").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({right: '-=25px'});
    });
});
```

**NOTE :** You could use just one `ready` function.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#one").click(function(){
      $("div").animate({top: '+=100px'});
  });
  $("#sec").click(function(){
      $("div").animate({top: '-=100px'});
  });
  $("#thi").click(function(){
      $("div").animate({right: '+=100px'});
  });
  $("#for").click(function(){
      $("div").animate({right: '-=100px'});
  });
});
```

```css
.box{
  background:grey;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="one">DOWN</button>
<button id="sec">TOP</button>
<button id="thi">LEFT</button>
<button id="for">RIGHT</button>

<br><br>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: `ready()` has been deprecated a long time ago, just use `$(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you have conflicting properties. If you want to move an element around, only use the `top` and `left` coordinates. Using `bottom` and `right` essentially tells the browser you want to stretch the element.

Also, the `.ready()` function has been deprecated for years in jQuery since `$(function() { ... })` does the same thing. See below.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#one").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({top: '0px'});
    });

    $("#sec").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({top: '250px'});
    });

    $("#thi").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
    });

    $("#for").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '0px'});
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
  background:grey;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="one">DOWN</button>
<button id="sec">TOP</button>
<button id="thi">LEFT</button>
<button id="for">RIGHT</button>

<br><br>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `top:0` for top click and `top:250px` for bottom click. similarly, you need to use `left:0` for left and `left:250px` for right click.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#one").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({top: '250px'});
    });

    $("#sec").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({top: '0'});
    });

    $("#thi").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '0'});
    });

    $("#for").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
  background:grey;
height:20px;
width:20px;
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="one">DOWN</button>
<button id="sec">TOP</button>
<button id="thi">LEFT</button>
<button id="for">RIGHT</button>

<br><br>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be a one $(document).ready(function(){}); and write inside all your needed code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#one").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({top: '+=250px'});
    });
    $("#two").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({top: '-=250px'});
    });
   $("#three").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({right: '+=250px'});
    });
   $("#four").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '+=250px'});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You might want to edit your answer, your code has a js error $ is not defined.

Comment: @NathanielFlick it's just because I don't reference the jQuery library, thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 1):

Using of attributes right and bottom is incorrect. See below:

```
$(function(){

    $("#one").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({top: '250px'});
    });

    $("#sec").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({top: '0px'});
    });

    $("#thi").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
    });

    $("#for").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '0px'});
    });
});
```

CSS :

```
.box{
    background-color:grey;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;    
}
```

Notice you need to only change the left and top attributes using Jquery.
This works correct. You can change the initial positions of the box using css and then move it accordingly in Jquery.